# Stripe email receipt subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following stripe's example for making subscriptions. I followed the example to where I got it to accept the payments. Sadly it is not sending an email receipt to the user that has made the payment. I went on to setting and allowed the emails. this has not done anything. I was reading in the docs that they don't send an email during the testing mode.

```
  const price = await stripe.prices.retrieve('priceId')

  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    email: user.email,
    name: `${user.firstname} ${user.surname}`,
  })

  const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
    customer: customer.id,
    items: [
      {
        price: price.id,
        quantity,
      },
    ],
    payment_behavior: 'default_incomplete',
    payment_settings: { save_default_payment_method: 'on_subscription' },
    expand: ['latest_invoice.payment_intent'],
  })
```

https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements&card-or-payment-element=card-element

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the email is set on the Customer object:

> To automatically send receipts, ensure that the customer’s email is set and the option email customers for successful payments is enabled in your email receipt settings.

See: https://stripe.com/docs/receipts#receipts-with-billing

If all this has been done, then I think you would need to reach out to Stripe support to find out what's going on.

Comment: I have it set in the customer object. I will contact support to see what they say

Comment: Can you let us know what you found?